# using "to" instead of "into" in "transform A into B"

Tags: verbs, prepositions

Instead of using "into", can I use the preposition "to"?

He transformed himself into a werewolf.

He transformed himself to a werewolf.

Answer (score 6):

Not really. Whilst any English speaker would know what you mean by either, in idiomatic English you transform **into** something. See the dictionary definition and usage guidance given by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/transform).

Transform has uses in other contexts, see the relevant examples given in
[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/transform) where it is not followed by **into**.